# How to use google recaptcha in nuxt?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, recaptcha

I am using nuxt and would like to use this library: https://github.com/nuxt-community/recaptcha-module. But I don't understand how to verify that the user has passed the check. The example doesn't tell me too much (https://github.com/nuxt-community/recaptcha-module/blob/master/example/v3/pages/index.vue). Could someone show me how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example is only half the story. It returns a Recaptcha V3 token on the client-side.

This must then be sent to the serverside and verified using your secret key.

This is done by sending a post to this URL:

```
const url = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secretKey}&response=${token}`;
```

You do not want to allow this secret key on the client side.

To achieve this in Nuxt, assuming version 2.13+, you can utilise `privateRuntimeConfig` in your nuxt config.

This will allow you to link a .env file to be injected only on the server side.

For this use case, a privateRuntimeConfig like this should suffice:

```
privateRuntimeConfig: {
    secretKey: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET
}
```

Once you have done this, you will be able to access these variables as part of `this.$config` within your Nuxt application - in this case `this.$config.secretKey` when calling the Recaptcha verify endpoint.

For more information [check out the Nuxt blog](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config#what-are-environment-variables)

Answer (score 3):

Use https://github.com/nuxt-community/recaptcha-module, in your `nuxt.config.js`

```
modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/recaptcha',
],

recaptcha: {
  hideBadge: true,
  siteKey: "ABC...", // Better would be from 'process.env.API_KEY' and with '.env' file
  version: 2, // Or 3
},
```

Keep in mind that `modules`, that's *not* the same as `buildModules` (sometimes it might confuse due to similar naming).

Comment: How about cheking secretKey?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working implementation for ReCaptcha V3:

*package.json*

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/recaptcha": "^1.0.4",
    "h3": "^0.3.9",
  },
```

Note the `h3` version. I wasn't able to get it working with a newer version of that because the library is converted to EJS/mjs and TypeScript, which conflicts with Nuxt. Transpiling `h3` didn't fix it. It may work with Nuxt V3+.

*nuxt.config.js*

```
  modules: [
    ['@nuxtjs/recaptcha', {
      siteKey: process.env.RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY,
      version: 3,
    }],
  ],

  serverMiddleware: [
    { path: '/api/check-token', handler: '~/middleware/recaptcha' },
  ],
```

*middleware/recaptcha.js*

```
import { useBody } from 'h3';
import axios from 'axios';

export default async (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  try {
    const { token } = await useBody(req);

    if (!token) {
      res.end(
        JSON.stringify({
          success: false,
          message: 'Invalid token'
        })
      );
      return;
    }

    axios.get(`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${process.env.RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY}&response=${token}`).then((answer) => {
      if (answer.status) {
        res.end(
          JSON.stringify({
            success: true,
            message: 'Token verified'
          })
        );
      } else {
        res.end(
          JSON.stringify({
            success: false,
            message: 'Invalid token'
          })
        );
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('ReCaptcha error:', e);
    res.end(
      JSON.stringify({
        success: false,
        message: 'Internal error'
      })
    );
  }
};
```

*.env*

```
RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY=gosei478htosvei478tvoei478tvge
RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY=ios47eos487t6es4897gtv6es487
```

*index.vue*

```
async mounted() {
    try {
        await this.$recaptcha.init();
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(`index# Problem initializing ReCaptcha: ${err}.`);
    }
},

beforeDestroy() {
    this.$recaptcha.destroy();
},

methods: {
    async submitContactForm() {
        try {
            const token = await this.$recaptcha.execute('contact')

            const formData = {
                email: this.contactForm.email,
                firstname: name.firstName,
                lastname: name.lastName,
                phone: this.contactForm.phone,
                band_name: this.contactForm.band_name,
                initial_message: this.contactForm.message,
            }

            // note: use POST request
            const recaptcha = await this.$axios.post('/api/check-token', { token });

            console.log('recaptcha', recaptcha.data);

            if (recaptcha.data.success) {
                const result = await this.$axios.post(process.env.CONTACT_FORM_API, formData);


                // cleanup logic
            } else {
                // handle error case
            }
        } catch (err) {
            // handle errors
        }
    },
},
```

You can read more here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/recaptcha

Note the section where it says

> Server Side
> When you send data + token to the server, you should verify the token on the server side to make sure it does not requested from a bot. You can find out how to verify token on the server side by looking at the server middleware inside v2 example. (The server side is same for both versions)

The above server-side middleware comes from there. It is important to use the version of `h3` that I suggest because you need it to access `useBody(req)`. I tried for several hours to find another way to read the request body but it proved too difficult. Your results may vary in a newer version of Nuxt. I suggest trying the newest version of `h3` and if that fails with errors when building the application, try the older version.

It is critically important to **not** expose the ReCaptcha secret key, and this solution keeps it secret in the server-side.

A more optimal solution might be to use your actual server and make an endpoint for validating ReCaptcha tokens. This above solution allows you to do it purely client-side, assuming you are using SSR.

Comment: upvoted! do you have to call recaptcha.init and recaptcha.destroy even for an invisible v2 recaptcha? the documentation doesnt mention anything here https://github.com/nuxt-community/recaptcha-module/tree/main